# Probability X>Y given X>Z

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent but non-identically distributed random variables. How do we find $\mathbb{P}(X > Y| X > Z)?$

EDIT: My attempt at a solution.

We have $\mathbb{P}(X>Y|X>Z) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>\max(Y,Z)}{\mathbb{P}(X>Z)}$. Writing $W = \max(Y,Z)$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(W \leq w) &= \mathbb{P}(Y\leq w)\mathbb{P}(Z\leq w)\\ &= F_Y(w)F_Z(w)
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X>W) &= \int_0^\infty F_W(x)f_X(x)dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty F_Y(x)F_Z(x)f_X(x)dx
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X>Y|X>Z) = \frac{\int_0^\infty F_Y(x)F_Z(x)f_X(x)dx}{\int_0^\infty F_Z(x)F_X(x) dx}
\end{align}

Comment: You find $\frac{\mathbb{P}(X > Y, X > Z)}{\mathbb{P}(X > Z)}$

Comment: Note $\mathbb{P}(X>Y, X>Z) = \mathbb{P}(X > \max(Y,Z))$ not $\min$. Whether the calculation is straightforward will depend on the details: if they are i.i.d. continuous random variables then you get $\frac{1/3}{1/2}=\frac23$  but in other cases it will be more difficult

Comment: Thank you Henry, that is helpful. I've posted my attempt at a solution using a slightly different approach above, not sure if it's valid though...